# Мобильный шаблон

Tags: html, css

Кто может рассказать как сделать мобильный шаблон? 
Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой с автоподгонкой ширины сайта под ширину моб. устройства. То есть, захожу через мобильную Оперу и чтобы увидеть контент нужно его приблизить. При этом так же не реагируют на это изменение процентные значения ширины элементов, соответственно портится весь дизайн. 
У самого тега body ширина не установлена.

Answer (score 1):

### Это ставите в заголовок

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
```

---

P.s, для более тесной вёрстки указывайте min-width и max-width. Под opera mini следует указывать в стилях возле ссылок !important, иначе она не будет подчёркнута + много мобильных браузеров не умеют скруглять уголки, поэтому border-radius работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Мобильная опера пытается рендерить по-взрослому. С большим разрешением. Сделано это для того, чтобы сайты, на которых нет поддержки мобильных устройств, так же хорошо отображались.

Попытайтесь определить что за браузер просматривает страницу и генерить HTML в зависимости от этого: если мобильник, то с малой шириной, если комп - с нормальной